# br0 interface doesn't forward traffic

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge

I have debian server with a bridge interface. Everything is fine in terms of configuration, however I can't ping default gateway as well as internet (obviously). Any idea why?

```
root@UKLNDLABPI:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0

root@UKLNDLABPI:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.b827eb20770c   no      eth0
                            wlan0
root@UKLNDLABPI:~# ifconfig 
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:20:77:0c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe20:770c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:175454 (171.3 KiB)  TX bytes:74358 (72.6 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:20:77:0c  
          inet addr:169.254.91.34  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:293 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8740 (8.5 KiB)  TX bytes:13238 (12.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:50801 (49.6 KiB)  TX bytes:50801 (49.6 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:75:22:59  
          inet addr:169.254.180.198  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1403 errors:0 dropped:13 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:939 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:169864 (165.8 KiB)  TX bytes:104371 (101.9 KiB)

root@UKLNDLABPI:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
#   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto br0
iface br0 inet static 
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge_ports eth0 wlan0

root@UKLNDLABPI:~# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```